# Aplicação baseada em multiplos perfis de autorização

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails

Estou com um punhado de dúvidas em um cenário interessante, espero que possam me dar uma ajudinha.

Estou utilizando em uma aplicação angular o pacote [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) para autenticação, para controle de permissões o pacote [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission), meu backend Rails está configurado com [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) para autenticação, [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) para autorização e [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) para multiplus perfis.

Preciso implementar e configurar para meu frontend com [roles](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission/wiki/Managing-roles) e [permissions](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission/wiki/Managing-permissions) utilizando o pacote [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission), nesse ponto não sei a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Devo passar as regras e permissões junto com a sessão do usuário? [Essa issue explica](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/158) um pouco como deveria ser.

Gostaria da opinião e experiência de vocês.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que vi na documentação do angular-permission, a checagem da permissão é assíncrona, então você pode tanto rodar com os dados locais como fazer uma requisição para o servidor sobre a permissão.

As permissões são segurança do servidor, mas esses dados são importantes na view, então vai depender muito de como está seu projeto e o quão complexo são suas roles e permissions.

De um modo geral eu sempre deixo regras de frontend no frontend, nesse caso, eu criaria um service responsável pela aquisição e storage desses roles para serem definidos no angular-permission, fazendo um loop nesses dados e setando todos rápidamente e atualizando quando necessário. Mas se existem muitas regras esse arquivo pode acabar ficando grande e ocupando tanto memória como processamento da sua aplicação (isso pode ser um problema especialmente se você também tem usuários mobile).

Se isso for um problema, altere a estratégia e faça as requisições para o servidor para cada caso (e vá adicionando as permissões por demanda), você vai perder em velocidade (vai ter mais requisições) mas vai ocupar menos memória e vai deixar seu projeto um pouco mais complexo.

No final você vai ter que colocar na balança para decidir qual seria a melhor solução para seu problema, mas se possível tente deixar esses dados no frontend (vai deixar seu projeto mais simples e desenvolvimento mais dinâmico).